# Error: have white space right side on Mobile ??? [bootstrap3]

Tags: html, css

This is code:

```
    
    <body>
    <ul style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
       <li style="display: block; float: left; width: 33%; background: pink; margin: 0; padding: 0;">jajaadjad d</li>
       <li style="display: block; float: left; width: 47%; background: green; margin: 0; padding: 0;">jajaadjad d</li>
       <li style="display: block; float: left; width: 20%; background: black; margin: 0; padding: 0;">jajaadjad d</li>
    </ul>
    </body>
```

On mobile, have a white space on right side! Please advise how to fix it.

Comment: Which mobile browser? Also, is there any CSS on the body? Some browsers apply a margin to the body by default. Can you also put this on jsFiddle?

Comment: Which mobile browser? - Google Chrome on Android.
   is there any CSS on the body? - No CSS on the body.

   I just import some css default of Bootstrap:css/bootstrap.min.css, js/bootstrap.min.js   That's all.

Thanks for reply :))

Comment: Since you're supposedly using bootstrap, why aren't you using bootstrap classes to style these? Bootstrap puts in considerable effort to make stuff work - your manual approach is very likely to clash with that and break stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an Android device handy to test this, but I suspect the issue is the default styles on the body tag, try replacing the body tag with:

```
  <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Use the inline-block style for each and every li

```
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <ul style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
       <li style="display: inline-block; float: left; width: 33%; background: pink; margin: 0; padding: 0;">jajaadjad d</li>
       <li style="display: inline-block; float: left; width: 47%; background: green; margin: 0; padding: 0;">jajaadjad d</li>
       <li style="display: inline-block; float: left; width: 20%; background: black; margin: 0; padding: 0;">jajaadjad d</li>
    </ul>
    </body>
```

Comment: Are you using jquery mobile

Comment: Not jquery! Only css and html like above. ( with <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />). Code is very simply, but i dont understand why have white space on right side in Google Chorme on Android...

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/view/63q4lah2uff2l1o/index1.html
This is link demo, i tried!

Answer (score 0):

try :
      body {
      overflow-x:hidden !important; 
      }

Comment: This might work in this instance, but `!important` is very much the nuclear option, and may make a total mess of bootstrap.